# Computing Gauss curvature using Meusnier theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I have troubles with finding Gauss curvature and mean curvature in a certain point of an oblique cylindrical surface. I know the way using the fundamental forms, but I am supposed to use the Meusnier theorem. I guess I should compute the principal curvatures (the non-zero one), but I don't know how.

Thank you for your help!

Karolina

Comment: Can you compute normal curvature for a point in an arbitrary direction? (if you can they are maximum and minimum values.)

Comment: I can't find the connection to Meusnier theorem

Comment: Calculating Gauss curvature has no connection to Meusnier theorem in my opinion. this theorem calculate no thing.

Comment: There should be a connection according to my teacher :D I think you can somehow use the theorem for cylindrical surfaces (I'm not sure if it's useful for any other type of a surface).

Comment: I think I found it. I have to use the formula explained here http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Meusnier's+Theorem Thank you for your help anyway!